# Can anyone identify this chrysalis? (Identified)

Tags: species-identification

It's about 5 or 6 cm long. It's on the outside (north facing) wall of my garage about a metre above ground level.

Photo taken in Thailand near Hua Hin (about 12N 100E) in December 2014.

[image: unknown chrysalis]

Comment: What a great find! :D Fantastic chrysalis. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I've found it** - it's a Common Rose Swallowtail (Pachliopta aristolochiae)

A few images on this page.
http://flickrhivemind.net/Tags/aristolochiae,butterfly/Interesting including these two

[image: Pupa]

[image: Pupa and butterfly]

There is a picture also at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachliopta_aristolochiae but this one is upside down compared to mine.

[image: Wikipedia image]

Mystery solved.